# Exporting NDVI result data as a table using Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How can I calculate and make NDVI result for each shapefile in one horizontal line in Excel?

[image]

```
//

var Akdarya = ee.FeatureCollection("users/xodjayevshovkat/Akdarya_GEE_35");

Map.centerObject(Akdarya)
//Define a geometry.
Map.addLayer(Akdarya);

// Make the geometry a feature collection.

// Import S2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  // Filter collection.
  .filterDate('2018-05-01','2018-09-30')
  .filterBounds(Akdarya)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20);

// Define a cloud masking function.
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
  var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1))
};


//

// Define an index function (return only NDVI).
var NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)', 
    {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'), 
      'RED': image.select('B4'), 
    }).rename('NDVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
};

// Apply the cloud mask function.
var NDVIcol = S2.map(maskcloud1)
 // Apply the NDVI transformation.
 .map(NDVI);

// Calculate the per-pixel median/mean NDVI for all images in collection.
var NDVImed = NDVIcol.mean();

// Define vis params.
var NDVIvis = {min: -0.001, max: 0.9, palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
    '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'};

//




// create a collection of the NDVI

var NDVIclip = NDVImed.clipToCollection(Akdarya)


// get the mean value for the region from each image
var regions = Akdarya.toList(Akdarya.size())
var ts = NDVIcol.map(function(image){
  var date = image.date().format("Y-M-D");
  var index = ee.String(Akdarya.get('Farmers'))
  var mean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: Akdarya,
    scale: 30,
   });

// and return a feature with 'null' geometry with properties (dictionary)  
  return ee.Feature(null, {'mean': mean.get('NDVI'),
                            'date': date})
});

// Export a .csv table of date, mean NDVI for watershed
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ts,
  description: 'NDVI_test4',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open your [CSV file](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c0ef682554ed8c442840ea8a5169cebf) in Excel, it has this aspect (I erased first row with only text).

```
20180505T061629_20180505T062110_T41TQE  0.375713612725906   
20180505T061629_20180505T062110_T42SUJ  0.378097012648882   
20180505T061629_20180505T062110_T42TTK  0.376428218677259   
.
.
.
20180927T061631_20180927T062415_T42SUJ  0.394643618813625
20180927T061631_20180927T062415_T42TTK  0.355055233079762
20180927T061631_20180927T062415_T42TUK  0.344509998290876
```

You only need the date before first underscore and, shapefile code is placed after second underscore. So, in **Data -> Text to columns**, split by underscore character ( _ ) and delete second column with dates. It will be similar to:

```
20180505T061629 T41TQE  0.375713612725906
20180505T061629 T42SUJ  0.378097012648882
20180505T061629 T42TTK  0.376428218677259
.
.
.
20180927T061631 T42SUJ  0.394643618813625
20180927T061631 T42TTK  0.355055233079762
20180927T061631 T42TUK  0.344509998290876
```

Now, you only need dates before T character so, split by this character resulting in:

```
20180505    T41TQE  0.375713612725906
20180505    T42SUJ  0.378097012648882
20180505    T42TTK  0.376428218677259
.
.
.
20180927    T42SUJ  0.394643618813625
20180927    T42TTK  0.355055233079762
20180927    T42TUK  0.344509998290876
```

Following path is sorting by code shapefile. Result it wil be similar to this:

```
20180612    T41TQE  0.304787176423969
20180614    T41TQE  0.278589926289108
20180617    T41TQE  0.295579423525899
.
.
.
20180505    T42SUJ  0.378097012648882
20180525    T42SUJ  0.350569571735592
20180609    T42SUJ  0.314428140852963
.
.
.
```

As there are four code zones in your data, manually, cut and paste by each code as follows; preserving only one of them as header. At this point you have each code ordered in one horizontal line in Excel. However, you will have to match dates in each case.

[image]

After that, you will be able to erase three unnecessary columns with dates. Finally, change dates (they are numbers) in text and, with the option "Fields" of **Data -> Text to columns**, divide en groups of 4, 2, 2 to obtain result of following image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This require some fiddling. For each image in `NDVIcol`, you can calculate the mean NDVI for each region, and assemble them into a single `ee.Feature`.

There seems to be limitation on the property names of a feature - dots doesn't seem to be allowed. Here I've replaced all "strange" (not a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) characters with underscore: `replace('\\W', '_', 'g')`.

Finally, when exporting, I specified the selectors property. This allows you to remove useless columns (system:index, .geo), and provide the order of the columns in the resulting CSV. That again requires some fiddling. The selectors must be a client-side (non EE) object. Here I'm calling `evaluate()`, to convert the selectors from a server-side to a client-side object.

```
var ts = NDVIcol.map(calculateFarmersNDVI)

function calculateFarmersNDVI(image) {
  var properties = ee.Dictionary(
    Akdarya.iterate(function(region, acc) {
      return ee.Dictionary(acc)
        .combine(
          ndviForArea(image, ee.Feature(region))
        )
    }, ee.Dictionary())
  )
  return ee.Feature(null, properties
    .set('Year', image.date().get('year'))
    .set('Month', image.date().get('month'))
    .set('Day', image.date().get('day'))
  )
}

function ndviForArea(image, region) {
  var ndvi = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region.geometry(),
    scale: 30
  }).get('NDVI')
  // Not all characters are valid property names in EE
  // dictionaries. Replace them with _
  var farmers = region.getString('Farmers')
    .replace('\\W', '_', 'g')

  // There might be images without any value for the region.
  // ee.Dictionary.set() must have a non-null value.
  // The If() statement replaces null with an empty string.
  var ndviOrBlank = ee.Algorithms.If(ndvi, ndvi, '')
  return ee.Dictionary().set(farmers, ndviOrBlank)
}

var listOfFarmers = ee.List(Akdarya.aggregate_array('Farmers'))
  .map(function (farmers) { 
    return ee.String(farmers).replace('\\W', '_', 'g')
  })
ee.List(['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])
  .cat(listOfFarmers)  
  // We want to provide toDrive() selectors, to
  // get the CSV columns ordered. This must be a 
  // client-side object though, so we need to call
  // evaluate() on it before using it.
  .evaluate(function (selectors) {
    Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: ts,
      description: 'NDVI_test4',
      fileFormat: 'CSV',
      selectors: selectors
    })    
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9bfd1d9f45aae5001aae0dc3a6a0ca68

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel